# how to replace default console remote access server

Tags: remote-desktop

I used to access a headless machine running 20.04 over the LAN by the built-in screen sharing function, using RealVNC on my desktop.

However, since I upgraded to 21.10, I ran into that weird problem where the VNC server misinterprets something about the screen resolution and the scaling factor, and only the top left quadrant of the screen shows up on the client.

Apparently this can only be [worked around](https://gitlab.gnome.org/Archive/vino/-/issues/9) by patching vino's source and recompiling, which I'm not willing to do. Weirdly, I uninstalled vino, only gnome-remote-desktop is installed, but the issue remains. I don't really know what's going on in the background, and I basically gave up figuring it out.

So, this question is about what is the best/recommended way to just install another VNC server (Tight? Real?) with automatic start on boot, and set it up to reliably and securely share the console session? I've read a lot of solutions regarding VNC, but most provide virtual desktop sessions, or rely on x11vnc which seems to be quite outdated to me. But if it's not, and is able to serve over modern SSL which is accessible through ordinary Windows VNC clients, I'm open to that, too.

Comment: What VNC server are you using?

Comment: I believe currently it's gnome-remote-desktop.

Comment: According to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers, the default VNC server is a program called `vino`. I know that you said you are using `gnome-remote-desktop`, but I honestly don't think the package is the server itself. I think it is the graphical environment for the VNC server. To see which VNC server you are using,  try running `cat /usr/bin/vncserver` and record the output either in your question or in the comments.

Comment: `vino` is not at all anymore on my system, and as I've learnt is deprecated by now. I read that it got _replaced_ by `gnome-remote-desktop`. in any case, that's the only process on my system plausibly related to remote screen access; and there exists no `/usr/bin/vncserver`

Comment: Would you consider using the TightVNCServer package? To install, run `sudo apt-get install tightvncserver`

Comment: Sure, as mentioned in the question, too. I don't know though what's the recommended way to set it up to start on boot, and serve my console session (possibly even serving both the login screen beforehand).